# DataReader - Will returning an enumerable/queryable be more performant than returning a list?

Tags: c#, .net

If a data reader releases data as it receives it, then using enumerables should allow that data to be immediately sent back to callers from a data access function.

If I use List based methods then callers would be waiting for all of the data to be received since the entire reader must be "enumerated" to be converted to a list.

Is this understanding correct and as a result is it *generally* faster to avoid using lists for returning collections when writing data access code using data readers?

I am implying probably using a yield return in the data access function using the reader vs. initializing a list of objects and adding objects to a list which is then returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Not only that it's immediate, because of lazy evaluation, but it also prevents unnecessary memory allocation, since you are only dealing with one row at a time.

Large amounts of data are best being left in the database.

Comment: he *will* create a list somewhere initially, if he iterates throuygh all the results. its hard for me to see how it will waste less memory.

Comment: @YavgenyP. It's a consideration if the item returned is binned as soon as it's processed.

Comment: @YavgenyP: there is no need to create a list anywhere. If you `yield return` results from your DAL method, which is internally advancing one row at a time using `DataReader.Read()`, your clients are only receiving one item at a time. If you are doing some sort of map/reduce  on a relational database, you will probably want to do it this way.

Comment: yeah it makes sense, unless he expects to use the entire set eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by faster

I look at it as batch versus end to end.

e.g. if you wanted to display an instance created for the row in a reader. Then returning IEnumerable would give you a chance and doing it without the unfortunate stutter that waiting for all the instances you are enumerating to be creating.

Another issue is the lifetime of whatever you are returning. If it's going to go out of scope as soon as it's processed, then IEnumerable is the way to go, as List would mean allocaing memory for all of them, where IEnumerable would be enough for one at a time.

Another issue would be how long it takes to process one of the enumerated items, never struck me as good idea to keep the reader open for an appreciable length of time, I've always been a big believer in small and quick in terms of client interactions with a database.

So generally true is the way I'd put it.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 different concepts youre talking about; one requires working in a connected mode (the streaming method, which will return results asap), while the other will get the results and release the connection. i dont think faster is an accurate term here. If you have N records, they wont get faster to the client, especially if any aditional computing is required. The client will maybe see *some* of the results faster, but probably not the entire list (and this is something that can be easily measured in each particular case), and youll have to pay in additional performance from the code that will keep the callers synchronized with the results (something like a concurrent collection).

In a web enviornment, for example, this can be done, but at very high cost of code writing/managing and synchronizing, which, I think, is not worth the effort in most of the cases.